# comparing 2 files in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have 2 files that I want to see if the contents inside are equal or not .Say one of them is a text file like Sample1.txt and the other one is a different file like main.css how can I compare the two to see if the contents inside are the same.

I was thinking like

```
Content1 = FSO.OpenTextFile(sample.txt).ReadAll
Content2 = FSO.OpenTextFile(main.css).ReadAll
if(Content1 = Content2) Then


End IF
```

Is there some better way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Depends **what you mean with *better***. If they're pretty big you may first **check for their size** (different sizes -> different content). For the same reason you may **not need to read them all in memory**, a character by character comparison may work for you (there you may even decide to ignore some kind of differences, for example double newlines). Note that character by character may not work for **Unicode surrogates** so a **line by line comparison** can be a better solution.

Comment: I think you're better off using a dedicated diff program, such as WinDiff or even the FC command (if they're still around)

Comment: The files can be around 2 mb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your just interested in whether or not the files are different the easiest way would be shelling out to [`fc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc):

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

Function AreDifferent(f1, f2)
  cmd = "%COMSPEC% /c fc /b " & qq(f1) & " " & qq(f2)
  AreDifferent = CBool(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(cmd, 0, True))
End Function
```

Comment: If I have to use `fc` I would compare text files with `/u` instead of `/b` (especially if I don't care about case) but I'd prefer to don't use it at all: if I just need to know if they're different I don't have to see/count all differences.

Comment: I tried the code above but it is always returning -1 even if the files are changed or not...I am passing the path's to the files are arguments which is a network path

Comment: One of the file is a text file and the other can be a css or js or some other extension file..I just need to see if the inside content is same or different

Comment: I get `True` (-1) for different files, and `False` (0) for identical files. Network drive or local doesn't make a difference.

Comment: sorry my bad..this answer is correct and super awesome..thanks